# Modify arguments to typing.NamedTuple prior to instance creation

Tags: python, type-hinting, namedtuple

I was looking forward to using the somewhat new `typing.NamedTuple` class, which allows the creation of named tuple classes using the usual Python class syntax (including the ability to add docstrings and methods,  provide default values, type hints, etc etc).

However: the class at the bottom is producing the following error message:

```
AttributeError: Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute __new__
```

From this I gather just what it says: overriding `__new__` is a still no-no. This is very disappointing.

The "old way" of going about this would be to inherit from a named tuple class, but this requires what I consider to be some ugly boilerplate code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class FormatSpec(namedtuple('FormatSpecBase', 'fill align sign alt zero '
                                              'width comma decimal precision type')):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, fill, align, sign, alt, zero,
                width, comma, decimal, precision, type):
        to_int=lambda x: int(x) if x is not None else x
        zero=to_int(zero)
        width=to_int(width)
        precision=to_int(precision)
        return super().__new__(cls, fill, align, sign, alt, zero,
                               width, comma, decimal, precision, type)

FormatSpec.__doc__=_FormatSpec.__doc__.replace('FormatSpecBase','FormatSpec')
```

Is there some other alternate way I can cast the `zero`, `width`, and `precision` arguments below to `int` prior to the creation of the named tuple, but still using the same class creation syntax? Or am I stuck using the old way?

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional

class FormatSpec(NamedTuple):
    """Represents a string that conforms to the [Format Specification
    Mini-Language][1] in the string module.

    [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec
    """
    fill: Optional[str]
    align: Optional[str]
    sign: Optional[str]
    alt: Optional[str]
    zero: Optional[int]
    width: Optional[int]
    comma: Optional[str]
    decimal: Optional[str]
    precision: Optional[int]
    type: str
    def __new__(cls, fill, align, sign, alt, zero, width, comma, decimal, precision, type):
        to_int=lambda x: int(x) if x is not None else x
        zero=to_int(zero)
        width=to_int(width)
        precision=to_int(precision)
        return super().__new__(cls, fill, align, sign, alt, zero,
                               width, comma, decimal, precision, type)
    def join(self):
        return ''.join('{!s}'.format(s) for s in self if s is not None)
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        try:
            return format(self.join(), format_spec)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return super().__format__(format_spec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to split this up into two classes, and do the arguments modification in the child class:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional

class FormatSpecBase(NamedTuple):
    """Represents a string that conforms to the [Format Specification
    Mini-Language][1] in the string module.

    [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec
    """
    fill: Optional[str]
    align: Optional[str]
    sign: Optional[str]
    alt: Optional[str]
    zero: Optional[int]
    width: Optional[int]
    comma: Optional[str]
    decimal: Optional[str]
    precision: Optional[int]
    type: str
    def join(self):
        return ''.join('{!s}'.format(s) for s in self if s is not None)
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        try:
            return format(self.join(), format_spec)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return super().__format__(format_spec)


class FormatSpec(FormatSpecBase):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, fill, align, sign, alt, zero, width, comma, decimal, precision, type):
        to_int=lambda x: int(x) if x is not None else x
        zero=to_int(zero)
        width=to_int(width)
        precision=to_int(precision)
        return super().__new__(cls, fill, align, sign, alt, zero,
                                    width, comma, decimal, precision, type)
```

I don't much care for this approach, but at least it is more readable than the "old way" (even though it still needs that hanging `__slots__` nonsense).

Another way would be a factory:

```
def MakeFormatSpec(cls, fill, align, sign, alt, zero,
                   width, comma, decimal, precision, type):
    to_int=lambda x: int(x) if x is not None else x
    zero=to_int(zero)
    width=to_int(width)
    precision=to_int(precision)
    return FormatSpec(fill, align, sign, alt, zero,
                      width, comma, decimal, precision, type)

fspec = MakeFormatSpec(*parse_format_spec(some_format_spec_string))
```

...or a factory method:

```
    @classmethod
    def make(cls, fill, align, sign, alt, zero, width, comma, decimal, precision, type):
        to_int=lambda x: int(x) if x is not None else x
        zero=to_int(zero)
        width=to_int(width)
        precision=to_int(precision)
        return cls(fill, align, sign, alt, zero,
                   width, comma, decimal, precision, type)

fspec = FormatSpec.make(*parse_format_spec(some_format_spec_string))
```

However, these are both pretty clunky compared to simply being able to do:

```
fspec = FormatSpec(*parse_format_spec(some_format_spec_string))
```

Comment: It's kind of funny to do a google search and end up clicking into one of your own previous Q and A sessions from SO. Ran into the same issue 6 years later in a complete different context and couldn't remember how to handle it. Thanks, past-Rick.